# Is this code legal in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constants, const-correctness

I just found that when it comes to templates this code compiles in g++ 3.4.2 and works unless m() is not called:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
     T e;

     public:
        C(): e(0) {};

    void m()
    {
        e = 0;
    };
 };
```

Now one may create and use instance

```
C<const int> c;
```

Until `c.m()` is not called there are no compile errors but is this legal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is legal.  The template specification is that until a method is instantiated, it doesn't exist and therefor is not checked by the compiler.  Here's the relevant bit from [the spec](http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/template.html):

> **14.7.1 - Implicit instantiation**
>
> -9- An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a member template, a
>   non-virtual member function, a member
>   class or a static data member of a
>   class template that does not require
>   instantiation.

Comment: Broadly correct but to be more precise, it should speak about a method being instantiated, rather than invoked. Apart from invoking it, taking a member pointer to it will also do it; and if a method is virtual, it's implementation-defined whether instantiation is deferred or not.

Comment: At least anything dependent on the template type. There is some confusion with non-dependent errors. E.g VC++ would accept even complete gibberish in the method as long as you don't invoke it (`non-sense here;`), however other compilers won't accept that even if you don't instantiate the template at all (which is probably more correct).

Comment: Anyone knows what's the intention of standard? I don't need for example to specialize code for const version of template at least at current level of my app (probably I will in future for the clarity). But is this a case?

Comment: I think it's in the same spirit as SFINAE - it lets you do things with templates which you can't otherwise do without a lot of defensive special-casing. Namely, write stuff that doesn't work with certain template parameters, and have that not matter as long as it doesn't need to work. I'd say this is a case - for instance you might write something to be a bounds-checked iterator over an array, and it would just naturally work over an array of const too. Quite rightly it would fail if a user did `*it = 0;` (because `*it` would return `T&` with T being a const-qualified type), but not before.

Comment: The Standard says that a template is ill-formed if no valid specialization can ever be generated out of it, but it says emitting a diagnostic is not required. In this case, however, "T" could be non-const, so the compiler cannot just emit an error for the template. And even if you would write "T const c;" as the member, it could be a class-type with a const "operator=".

Comment: You're right, in my example it's not the template member function which is wrong, it's the code which calls it. Oops.